# Coverting Simple3Des(VB.net) encryption-decryption code to python

Tags: python, vb.net, encryption, 3des

I'm have a plain JSON text which is encrypted using Triple-DES in Visual Basic(code provided below), now I'm trying to decrypt it using python language. when I test it I'm getting the wrong output.
I think there is any padding issue because I didn't get this line:

```vb
ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)
```

VB code:

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class Simple3Des
    Private TripleDes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

    Private Function TruncateHash(ByVal key As String, ByVal length As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim sha1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

        ' Hash the key.
        Dim keyBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key)
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes)

        ' Truncate or pad the hash.
        ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)

        Return hash
    End Function

    Sub New(ByVal key As String)
        ' Initialize the crypto provider.
        TripleDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, TripleDes.KeySize \ 8)
        TripleDes.IV = TruncateHash("", TripleDes.BlockSize \ 8)
    End Sub

    Public Function EncryptData(ByVal plaintext As String) As String
        ' Convert the plaintext string to a byte array.
        Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext)

        ' Create the stream.
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream

        ' Create the encoder to write to the stream.
        Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms,
            TripleDes.CreateEncryptor(),
            System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
        encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the encrypted stream to a printable string.
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

    Public Function DecryptData(ByVal encryptedtext As String) As String
        ' Convert the encrypted text string to a byte array.
        Dim encryptedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext)

        ' Create the stream.
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream

        ' Create the decoder to write to the stream.
        Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms,
            TripleDes.CreateDecryptor(),
            System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

 
        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length)
        decStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the plaintext stream to a string.
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray)
    End Function
End Class
```

Here is my approach with different paddings and combinations:

```py
from pyDes import *
import hashlib
import base64

key = b'Hi4Q=rLJnyqPj$G_cTqDcwgWo'
sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1(key).digest()

key_ = sha1_hash[:len(key)//8]
# key_ = sha1_hash[:-4]
# key_ = sha1_hash

base64Encrypted = r'''...'''
base64Decrypted = base64.b64decode(base64Encrypted)
print ("output: ", k.decrypt(base64Decrypted))
```

Am I doing something wrong?